# multiple root tags for <FrameLayout>

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I keep receiving a multiple root tags at the  and i have no idea why do I have this error, can any kind soul please explain to me why is it so? Thanks in advance :) BTW i am current trying to do a Geo location on a blank activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"   
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="attr/colorPrimary"app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"     
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"><fragment
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
android:id="@+id/map" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @TommySM thank you soo much :)

Answer (score 1):

The lines:

```
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

should appear in the root element, meaning, only once at the top, you have it twice, an XML document can only have 1 root element, so you also need the closing tag to wrap at the bottom.

something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/some_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <!--stuff you want inside the coordinator ... -->
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

   <!--stuff you want in general here ... -->
  </RelativeLayout>
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1) Include all the other widgets within the Linear Layout as such

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width...
>
<EditText
android:..
/>
<?LinearLayout>
```

Since, there can only be one root element.

2) Add all of the `xlmns` statements in the `LinearLayout` field (at the beginning) without and repetition. `xlmns` should appear in the parent root.